# Application Context, after being initialized, keeps reloading

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a problem with starting the StandardContext in my web application using Struts2, spring and Apache Tomcat. The server continues reloading and does not stop itself. The following code is repeated continuously.

```
set 21, 2015 2:26:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/My_Web_Service] has started
set 21, 2015 2:26:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
set 21, 2015 2:26:44 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

I have to load a file of properties and I used this but doesn't work:

```
<bean id="placeHolderBean"
        class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:myFile.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="replacerBean" class="it.vptech.util.editor.PasswordPlaceholderReplacer">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:myFile.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="0"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Do you perform some file operations on app startup?

Comment: I want to load a properties file in the application context using spring annotations.

Comment: A replacer? Don't write to files and context won't be reloaded.

Comment: You're right. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to write to files, set the "reloadable" to false.

Read this on the "reloadable" section > https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html
"Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected."

Pardon the brevity, sent from mobile